# Django 1.6: Displaying two models in template using SingleObjectMixin & ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Working on an application were I have a Many to One relationship where I have many Products and a few particular products will be related to only one Brand.

In my Detail View I have the logic set to display specific information about each brand in the designated template based on the slug entered in the field of My Brand Model. My problem is when I add and extra context variable to loop through each product it returns all the products I currently have in the db and not the ones related to the particular brand based on the foreign key relationship.

Is their a way to solve this problem? Thank you!

**Model.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    """
    Information for each brand
    """

    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    brand_founded = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, null=True)

    brand_origin_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    brand_origin_state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

    brand_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    brand_product_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    #Shows details about specific brand
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Brand Slug'), unique=True,  null=True,  blank=True)

    brand_logo = CloudinaryField('Logo Image', null=True, blank=True)
    brand_feature_image = CloudinaryField('Featured Brand Image', null=True, blank=True)

    brand_website_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_email = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    #For the different active states for the brands
    brand_state = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Brand Available'))
    brand_location_state = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Location(s) Available'))
    brand_email_state = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Email Available'))

    # Whether brand is menswear, womenswear or both
    menswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Menswear'))
    womenswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Womenswear'))

    #For Admin Purposes and filtering, to keep track of new and old  in the database by administrative users
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Date added'))
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified')) 

class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Products for each brand
    """

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Product Name'), null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = CurrencyField( verbose_name=_('Unit price') )

    # Points to a Cloudinary image
    product_image = CloudinaryField('product image', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    #For Admin Purposes, to keep track of new and old items in the database by administrative users
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Date added'))
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified') )

    # Foreign Key
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True)
```

**View.py**

```
class BrandDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, ListView):

    template_name = 'brand_guides/_brandguide.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(queryset=Brand.objects.all())

        return super(BrandDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BrandDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['brand'] = self.object
        context['product_list'] = Product.objects.filter(brand__product=1)
        return context


    def get_queryset(self,  **kwargs):
    # qs = super(BrandDetailView, self).get_queryset(**kwargs)
        return self.object
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


    #url for brands
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)$', BrandDetailView.as_view(), name="brand_view"),
)
```

**brand_guides/_brandguide.html template**

```
<div class="section-text align-center mb-70 mb-xs-40">
                            {{ brand.brand_description }}                                  
                        </div>

{% for data in product_list %}
                <li class='col n-4'>
                    <div class='magazine-single-card-container medium'>
                        <div class='magazine-card magazine-product-card'>
                            <div class='magazine-product-img-container'>
                                <div class='hover-container'>

                                    <div class='product-image' style="background-image:url('{% cloudinary_url product.product_image PRODUCT %}');"></div>

                                    <div class='top-right'>
                                        <span class="card-price button-price">${{ data.product_price}}</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- <a class="card-view" href="javascript:void(0)"></a> -->

                                    <label class="card-name">{{ brand.product_name }}</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I need to add to **context['product_list']** in my **views.py** `self.object` to the Product Model's filter query since it is already accessing the foreign key relationship to my Brand Model using the variable **brand**  I am just retrieving the instance of the object from my get method and using it within the context of my view.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BrandDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['brand'] = self.object
        context['product_list'] = Product.objects.filter(brand=self.object)
        return context
```